# Gradle Kotlin DSL equivalent for Groovy DSL compilerArgs for compileJava?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

For the Gradle Java plugin, what is the Kotlin DSL equivalent for the following Groovy DSL?

```
compileJava { 
  options.compilerArgs += [ 
    '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true', 
    '-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true', 
    '-Amapstruct.verbose=true'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`compilerArgs`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.html#getCompilerArgs--) is a Java [`List<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which in Kotlin is [mapped](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types) to a [`MutableList<String>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/).

There are [a few different ways](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-write.html#adding-elements) to add elements to a mutable list in Kotlin. One option is to use [`addAll()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add-all.html)

```kotlin
tasks.compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs.addAll(
    listOf(
      "-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true",
      "-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true",
      "-Amapstruct.verbose=true",
    )
  )
}
```